# How to update a table depending on DFT status in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS Package to dump the data from file to database. I have 17 files and 17 tables, with 17 data flow tasks accomplishing this in the package.

I have another table containing a row(flag) for a file that will say dump is successful of failed. How can I update this table based on the data flow task status.

If DFT is failed then corresponding row should be updated to 0 else to 1.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use Precedence Constraints to Update Status]

Use Precedence Constraints. Read more here [Precedence Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261.aspx)

The basic idea is to update with the Execute SQL task the status on Success/Failure.

Example -
The `Failure -File Transfer 1` Execute SQL Task, will trigger on failure of `File Transfer 1` DFT and would set flag to 0.

The `Success -File Transfer 1` Execute SQL Task, will trigger on success of `File Transfer 1` DFT and would set flag to 1.